# Finding and converting XML processing instructions using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom, processing-instruction

We are converting our ancient FrameMaker docs to XML. My job is to convert this:

```
<?FM MARKER [Index] foo, bar ?>`
```

to this:

```
<indexterm>
    <primary>foo, bar</primary>
</indexterm>
```

I'm not worried about that part (yet); what is stumping me is that the `ProcessingInstruction`s are all over the documents and could potentially be under any element, so I need to be able to search the entire tree, find them, and then process them. I cannot figure out how to iterate over an entire XML tree using `minidom`. Am I missing some secret method/iterator? This is what I've looked at thus far:

- `Elementtree` has the excellent `Element.iter()` method, which is a depth-first search, but it doesn't process `ProcessingInstruction`s.
- `ProcessingInstruction`s don't have tag names, so I cannot search for them using `minidom`'s `getElementsByTagName`.
- `xml.sax`'s `ContentHandler.processingInstruction` looks like it's only used to create `ProcessingInstruction`s.

Short of creating my own depth-first search algorithm, is there a way to generate a list of `ProcessingInstruction`s in an XML file, or identify their parents?

Comment: Sounds like preprocessing for me - convert the PIs into normal tags, writing some small specialized preprocessing-script for that. Then, process  with ElementTree.

Comment: have you considered [lxml](http://lxml.de)? `tree.xpath('//processing-instruction()')` should return all PIs in the tree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the XPath API of the `lxml` module as such:

```
from lxml import etree

foo = StringIO('<foo><bar></bar></foo>')
tree = etree.parse(foo)
result = tree.xpath('//processing-instruction()')
```

> The node test processing-instruction() is true for any processing instruction. The processing-instruction() test may have an argument that is Literal; in this case, it is true for any processing instruction that has a name equal to the value of the Literal.

**References**

- [XPath and XSLT with lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)
- [XML Path Language 1.0: Node Tests](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests)