# Read XML prolog

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?foo class="abc"?>
<document>
 ...
</document>
```

frpm which I'd like to read the `foo` prolog using Python.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("bar.xml")
# ??
```

Any hints?

Comment: That's a processing instruction and here's how to get'em https://stackoverflow.com/a/49131506/2834978 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360183/finding-and-converting-xml-processing-instructions-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterparse() can show the event [pi](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) content:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse("bar.xml", events=("start", "end", "pi")):
    print(event, elem.text)
```

or with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("bar.xml")
result = tree.xpath('//processing-instruction()')
print(result)
```

or with SAX:

```
from xml.sax import make_parser, handler

class ProInst(handler.ContentHandler):
    def processingInstruction(self, target, data):
        print ('processing instruction:', target, data)


parser = make_parser()
b = ProInst()
parser.setContentHandler(b)
parser.parse("bar.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse


tree = parse('bar.xml')
node = tree.childNodes[0]
print(f'{node.nodeName}, {node.nodeValue}')

# or
for node in tree.childNodes:
    if node.nodeName == 'foo':
        print(node.data)
        break
```